# jQuery - Prepend to div not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to prepend a span containing a bootstrap glyphicon to the start of a div's content but the icon isn't showing.

Anything wrong with this JS?:

```
$(formMessages).prepend('<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span>');
```

EDIT: formMessages IS meant to be a variable, not a class or id. The only line of the following that doesn't work is the prepend:

```
.done(function(response) {
        $(formMessages).css('display', 'block');
        $(formMessages).removeClass('alert-danger');
        $(formMessages).addClass('alert-success');
        $(formMessages).prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
        $(form).css('display', 'none');

        $(formMessages).text(response);
```

Comment: Is `formMessages` a variable or is it the name of an element or class?

Comment: No need to escape your quotes in your example

Comment: is the span there when you look at it in the browser inspector?

Comment: What error messages do you get in the console?

Answer (score 0):

If `formMessages` is a class, it needs to be written like this:

```
$('.formMessages').prepend(...
```

Comment: It is meant to be a variable. Adding and removing classes from it works as intended. Only thing that doesn't work is the prepend

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to escape the quotation marks, when you have single outside the whole string, and double inside. This is quite a useful feature in javascript, and works both ways - you can have double quotes on the outside, single inside the string. Just don't have both types inside.

Anyway, removing backslashes, as there's no need for escaping, should make it work:

```
$(formMessages).prepend('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>');
```

And as others have pointed out, `$(formMessage)` will work only if `formMessage` is a variable. Use `$(".formMessage")` if it's a class or `$("#formMessage")` if id.

Comment: Have removed the backslashes but still isn't working. formMessage IS a variable consisting of a #formMessage div

Comment: Are you definitely loading the resources that include the icon? (Just a sanity check) Also, check @Iceman's snippet :)

Comment: Yes. I've used bootstrap throughout my site

Answer (score 0):

- Never escape until necessary. Here you used a single quote `'` to define a string. So, you need to escape only when you want to have a single quote in the string. For double quotes `"` it isn't required.
- You haven't provided enough code. But, I hope `formMessages` is a JS object.

**WORKING EXAMPLE**:

```js
var formMessages = document.getElementById("test_div");
$(formMessages).prepend('<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span>');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="test_div">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't trying to add anything within the span, it's only there to add the glyphicon. Yes, formMessages is a variable

Comment: @nickck15 that was there only for visual purposes to see the result. Feel free to replace with what you have.

Comment: No. My point is that the glyphicon doesn't appear even without the backslashes

Comment: @nickck15 made the update with bootstrap and glyphicon

Comment: Your example works but mine won't because I'm not trying to add a function to a button

Comment: @nickck15 Fyn, I've removed that, but it still works. y dont u put a fiddle with ur issue, i'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there is no mistake.

I guess that the "icon is not showing", does not mean that "in the DOM is missing". Try to check your styles. `glyphicons` just must have :before/:after element.